# Laravel Fetching error from database Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, eloquent

I am developing a Simple CRUD Application, 
I want to fetch my forms details from my **forms** table.

my controller look like below,

```
public function manage_forms()
{
    $form_data=Form::all();
    return View::make('manage_forms')->with('form_array',$form_data);
}
```

the routes.php,

```
Route::get('manage-forms',array('as'=>'manage_forms','uses'=>'Nri@manage_forms'));
```

the View file,

```
<title>Registered Form details</title>
<h2>Registered Form details</h2>

<ul>
@foreach($form_array as $form_view)
<li>{{$form_view->name}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

My Forms model (Form.php),

```
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
 use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

 class Form extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'forms';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

I am getting error like

```
 BadMethodCallException

 Method all does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your class name from Form to something else, as `Form::` is already in use by laravel itself and you can't use the same class more than once

Remember to run `php artisan dump-autoload` after changing

Here:

```
class Formdata extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {          
      // ^this needs to be changed 

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'forms';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

and this:

```
public function manage_forms()
{
    $form_data=Formdata::all();
                ^ and this
    return View::make('manage_forms')->with('form_array',$form_data);
}
```

Comment: where i can specify the model, i want to fetch from database table named forms,

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel_nri_test.formdatas' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `formdatas`)

Comment: you shouldn't change this: protected $table = 'forms'; - have you?

Comment: yes, now like this : <?php

class Formdata extends Eloquent  {
 protected $table = 'formdatas';

}

Comment: protected $table = 'forms'; has to stay like it is, youŕ table is called forms, I suppose

Comment: exactly as I wrote in my answer. Simply change class name Form to whatever you want and change nothing else.

Comment: $form_data=Formdata::all();  is this is currect ?

Comment: protected $table = 'forms';  i think this is wrong ..am i currect. ?

Comment: if your table is called forms it's correct. This needs to be the name of your table of course